How can I add text and image elements into div elements?
I have a HTML file with the following element:
<div id="projects-section" class="section">
            <h2>My Projects</h2>
            <div id="projects">

            </div>
            
        </div>

I created this function to generate n-number of div elements within the <div id="projects"> element:
function loadProjects() {
  // Write your code here
  for (var i=0; i<projects.length; i++){
    card = document.createElement('div')
    card.className = 'card'
    projectCard = document.getElementById("projects").appendChild(card)
  }
}

This is the "projects" array:
var projects = [
    {
    "title": "ToDo List App",
    "description": "This project is about a simple ToDo App.",
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/110473/pexels-photo-110473.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
},
{
    "title": "Calculator App",
    "description": "This project is about a Calculator App.",
    "image": "https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661311947753-065ef4af9087?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1032&q=80"
},
{
    "title": "Weather App",
    "description": "This project is about a Weather App.",
    "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1176320050/photo/weather-forecast-on-a-digital-display-7-day-dashboard-3d-illustration.jpg?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=cP1wxucPWNcaXOe9BgceXNb9aKTv0uDX3AoW2aSvAvg="
},
{
    "title": "Timer App",
    "description": "This project is about a Timer App",
    "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/533888785/photo/smartphone-stopwatch.jpg?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=UejoQeXXO4WV7xqSmXl4QaCQam509L7oxes7lpowJjg="
},
{
    "title": "Chat Application",
    "description": "This project is about a simple Chat Application.",
    "image": "https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1688822014591-30d7b089b43c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
}

]


So I'm now trying to add img elements into each of the 6 div elements I generated with the class = "card" with this on load:
projectCard = document.getElementsByClassName("card")
  for (i=0;i<projects.length;i++){
    image = document.createElement('img')
    image.src = projects[i]["image"]
    projectCard.appendChild(image)
  }

But this last piece of code is not displaying anything, nor is it generating any img elements.
Help please??
I need to get those image elements inside the  tags.

As you need to add images to the card you are adding in the projects section, so you can add the images before appending the card in the DOM. This way you can remove one extra loop from the code.


var projects = [
    {
    "title": "ToDo List App",
    "description": "This project is about a simple ToDo App.",
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/110473/pexels-photo-110473.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
},
{
    "title": "Calculator App",
    "description": "This project is about a Calculator App.",
    "image": "https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661311947753-065ef4af9087?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1032&q=80"
},
{
    "title": "Weather App",
    "description": "This project is about a Weather App.",
    "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1176320050/photo/weather-forecast-on-a-digital-display-7-day-dashboard-3d-illustration.jpg?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=cP1wxucPWNcaXOe9BgceXNb9aKTv0uDX3AoW2aSvAvg="
},
{
    "title": "Timer App",
    "description": "This project is about a Timer App",
    "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/533888785/photo/smartphone-stopwatch.jpg?s=612x612&w=is&k=20&c=UejoQeXXO4WV7xqSmXl4QaCQam509L7oxes7lpowJjg="
},
{
    "title": "Chat Application",
    "description": "This project is about a simple Chat Application.",
    "image": "https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1688822014591-30d7b089b43c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
}

]
  
  
function loadProjects() {
  // Write your code here
  for (var i=0; i<projects.length; i++){
    card = document.createElement('div')
    card.className = 'card'
    
    image = document.createElement('img')
    image.src = projects[i]["image"]
    card.appendChild(image);
    document.getElementById("projects").appendChild(card)
  }
}



loadProjects();
<div id="projects-section" class="section">
  <h2>My Projects</h2>
  <div id="projects"></div>
</div>



